# Page width renders different but CSS disagrees

Tags: css, width

Here are two pages which have the same width divs and margins, etc. with respect to the width. The inspector agrees on this point. However, the second one, 'Murals' seems less wide on render. Can you identify what is doing this?

http://www.aptart.org/about/

http://www.aptart.org/gallery/murals/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just side effect of the vertical scrollbar which is present in one page and not in the other one.

Comment: Yes, how silly. Frantic deployment troubleshooting panic! Thanks

Comment: For the record it's easily fixable so that all pages have scroll bars whether there is a need or not, personally I prefer this to the jumping back and forth. Add overflow:scroll; to the body CSS.